# Broadcom bcm4323 with ubuntu 12.04 having ndiswrapper problem

Tags: wireless, broadcom, ndiswrapper, netgear

I can't seem to get this wireless usb to work.  I have connected with a huge cable to my brothers-in-law internet upstairs, but I can't find it working. I have no idea what I need to do with the terminal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As of now the most annoying problem is that I get a 
`Fatal: ndiswrapper not found`.

Answer (score 0):

1.Install the packages `ndiswrapper-dkms ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-source` by `sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-dkms`.

2.Run `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`.

3.Calm down.

Comment: I am still getting the Fatal: module ndiswrapper not found.

Comment: good luck and pls approve my edit by clicking the inbox

Comment: ndiswrapper is tricky to install in 12.04. It installs from the Software Center easily in 14.04 and later. Would you rather upgrade or compile from source code?

Comment: Yes that's the main problem. Many packages are out-dated in 12.04.

Comment: well i had the 14.04 and it was too much for this computer - it ran incredibly slow.  I've tried what feels like 6 or 7 different threads from chili555 - which are incredible.  And i've learned so much - but i can't get away from the Fatal: module ndiswrapper not found.  how do i compile from source code.  it sounds so fancy.

Comment: i guess i'll try to upgrade and see if i can get it to work.  thank you for your time and help.

Comment: If the upgrade doesn't work, we'll compile the source code. Let us know.